# Price of a single item

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have this mathematical problem, and I don't know how to tackle it.

Total price of a jacket and shoes is $106$ euros.

The shoes cost $13$ more euros than the jacket.

How much does the jacket cost?

$S+J=106$

$S=J+13$

$J=?$

Is the question missing something?

With this question, can't the price of the jacket can be anything, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Perhaps if you write equations relating $J=$cost of jacket and $S=$cost of shoes you can solve them and get the answer

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3352951/how-to-calculate-two-integers-x-and-y-when-the-sum-of-xy-is-known-and-differenc)

Comment: I've added an edit to the post

Comment: Good!  Now subtract the second equation from the first

Comment: By the way this has nothing to do with percentages.

Comment: Edited to remove the 'percentages' tag.

Answer (score 1):

$$S+J=106\tag1$$

$$S-J=13\tag2$$

subtract $(2)$ from $(1)$:

$$2J=106-13$$

Now can you determine the price of the jacket?

Comment: Ye that should do the trick, I understand it from here. I'm sorry Im not the very brightest at Maths. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to solve the system $$j+s=106,\,s=j+13$$ for $j,$ with the variables standing for the obvious quantities.

This is a linear system of the form $x+y=a,\,x-y=b.$ This always has a unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, the question isn't missing anything. You can set it up as the equation 
106 = (13 + x) + x, where x is the price of the jacket and (13 + x) is the price of the shoe.

Comment: Oh, I posted my answer only after keeping the question opened in a tab for a while, during which others have already answered the question